# Не могу понять как на python написать функцию для вычисления номера страницы при парсинге сайта с bs4

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Всем привет. Пишу парсер [сайта](https://news.ycombinator.com/newest) на питоне используя bs4. Примитивами собираю некоторые тэги по статьям для формирования небольшой подборки данных. В питоне практически новичок. Пока процесс подстановки ссылки на страничку реализован на ручном приводе путем подстановки адреса конкретной страницы в код. Хотелось бы автоматизировать данный процесс. Для этого хочу написать функцию которая будет собирать все доступные адреса страниц в данном разделе. На текущий момент реализовано следующим образом (код не мой, взят с просторов интернета).

```
x=0
while True:
  try:
    if x == 0:
      page_link = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/news'
    else:
      page_link = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/news' + next_link
                   code
    search_morelink = soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'morelink'})
    morelink_get = search_morelink.get('href')
    next_link = morelink_get[4:]
    x += 1
  except:
    print('err')
```

Answer (score 0):

Да очень просто. Смотри: ты парсишь элементы. Например, их 50 на странице, если элементов меньше 50, то это последняя страница.

Конкретно в твоем случае:

```py
page=1
while True:
  r=requests.get(f'...?page={page}')
  s=BeautifulSoup(r.text)
  l=len(s.find_all('tr', {'class': 'athing'}))
  if l < 30:
    break
  page+=1
```

Comment: Как получить {page}? Проблема в том что страницы не начинаются с 1,2,3 и тд. Первая страница имеет вид https://news.site.com/newest, а следующая страница уже имеет вид https://news.site.com/newest?next=31967965&n=31. Так вот вопрос в том как автоматом получить next=31967965&n=31 и тд?

Comment: Вот эта запись "31967965&n" расчитывается динамически и не повторяется. По идее она прописывается в дом дереве где-то и ее надо спарсить, только я не пойму где она лежит и как это правильно сделать. По итогу адрес страницы будет иметь вид 'news.site.com/newest'+{hash}+'=31 (61, 91 и тд, пока элементов не будет меньше 30)'. В финале я должен получить список ликвидных страниц на момент запроса, которые уже потом будут переданы далее по коду для парсинга элементов.